# Push notification clicked detection issue

Tags: swift, push-notification

I am using application state to determine if user clicked on push notification. If application is in InActive State I am processing the push notification.It working fine normally. But if user put the app in background and then bring it back in foreground ( repeating this steps too frequently) and my app receive a push notification , app process the push notification because app is in inActive state. How to avoid this issue
?